# System.Web.HttpException File does not exist - Page loads just fine (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, log4net, application-error

I'm using Log4Net and logging everytime my ASP.NET-Application throws an error:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Log.Error("An error occurred", ex);
    }
```

Alas, everytime I visit a page on my application, a `System.Web.HttpException` is caught, "File does not exist".

Here's the Stack Trace:

```
bei System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
bei System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)
bei System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I don't have any clue how to debug this, this happens on my ASP.NET Development Server and on an IIS 7.5 I deploy it on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I bet it's the `favicon.ico` that Google Chrome always requests and which you forgot to include. But to be sure you could trace the request url:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    Log.Error("An error occurred", ex);
    Log.Error("Requested url: ", Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Now in your log file you should see:

```
Requested url: /favicon.ico
```

or something else like `robots.txt` when for example web crawlers attempted to crawl your site.

Comment: Yep, favicon.ico or robots.txt.

Comment: As it turns out it was the `favicon.ico` that Google Chrome always requests and which I forgot to include.

Comment: @DennisRöttger +1 Why did I encounter this error also , which is not found `favicon.ico` I was using Firefox . not chrome. thanks.

Comment: This is a nice tip. I used HttpContext.Current.Request.Url instead of Request.RawUrl

Answer (score 0):

I have same error:

There were some file references in CSS. That does not exist in directory. So it gave this error.
I created Image Files, so error disappeared.

So make sure that file reference that you have given is exists in your directory

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML output of your page in case of using url with tilda "~/"

You need to use @Url.Content() to fix it

http://clubmicrosoft.net/post/2014/02/28/File-does-not-exist.aspx