# “File does not exist” in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just started getting the “File does not exist” exception.  The exception occurs after I press the Run button in visual studio. Also as far as I can tell, none of my code is hit. The code part that should hit is

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
   return View("Index"); 
}
```

But the breakpoint in that code is never hit. .. I followed [How to solve exception "File does not exist"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705057/how-to-solve-exception-file-does-not-exist) and [System.Web.HttpException File does not exist - Page loads just fine (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517801/system-web-httpexception-file-does-not-exist-page-loads-just-fine-asp-net)
and wrote the following code:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex.Message == "File does not exist.")
    {
        var foo = Request.RawUrl;
        var newEx = new Exception(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()), ex);   
    }
}
```

Now when I run and hit this code, foo is set to "/" and newEX is "File does not exist. http://localhost:63456/"

Any ideas?

Here is the stack trace:

> > PishiWebSite.dll!PishiWebSite.MvcApplication.Application_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 164  C#
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError() + 0xc6 bytes
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.RecordError(System.Exception error) + 0x40 bytes
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x101 bytes
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) + 0xf8 bytes
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x284 bytes 
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x6e bytes
> >         System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x47 bytes
> >         WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process() + 0x188 bytes 
> >         WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection conn) + 0x66 bytes
> >         [Appdomain Transition]
> >         WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(object acceptedSocket) + 0xa1 bytes
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x3e bytes 
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x60 bytes 
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x149 bytes
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x5 bytes 
> >         [Native to Managed Transition]

Also typing `Server.GetLastError().StackTrace.ToString()` in the Imediate Window gives:

> at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
>      at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)
>      at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: What's the stack trace? Where is the code that causes the exception?

Comment: @mason, just added the stack trace

Comment: Why are you throwing the exception? That obscures where the error is occurring. Look at the ex object and inspect its properties. **But don't throw it!**

Comment: Is this only for a particular action, or for any url?

Comment: I think the stacktrace of the original exception retrieved from `Server.GetLastError()` would be more helpful.

Comment: @mason, I just followed the example I linked. The exception does not have to be re-thrown. The idea is whatever loging is done later in this code, the more detailed exception would be logged as apposed to the vague one ASP.NET originally provides.

Comment: Take out the `throw newEx` and don't create a new exception object. Just inspect `ex` to see what the stacktrace is. Also make sure you look at any inner exceptions.

Comment: The stackTrace I posted was for the original error, before the "throw newEx;" is hit. I will remove that line from the code to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I also added stack trace info obtained via a different way

Comment: Are you doing any AJAX calls anywhere? Could be dying there in which case the page may still appear to load fine.

Comment: @garryp This has nothing to do with AJAX. The error hits after I press the Run button in visual studio. Also as far as I can tell, none of my code is hit. The code part that should hit is         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        } but that is never hit. Also I am pretty sure that I am not missing any files.

Comment: Are you pointing to the ActionResult with a RedirectToAction? These can throw weird silent exceptions sometimes. Might be a good idea to post relevant code from your controller too

Comment: @garryp The controller is never hit.

Comment: Check in the project properties to see what is set for the startup URL. Also, try Debug->Start without debugging, then browse to your index page directly: `http://localhost:port/index`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, 1. Start Action is CurrentPage and I usually start when the active page is the controller page (this way it defaults to the index page). 2. Debug->Start gives me the my default error that I have set up in ApplicationError method in Global.asax. 3. Browsing directly to http://localhost:port/index causes this exception: File does not exist. http://localhost:63400/index. But: browsing to http://localhost:63400/home/index works. What is going on?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks, I had deleted a controller method and the routing associated with it and for some odd reason, that broke things.

Comment: Please add that as an answer. Show how your deletion of the route led to this problem. Others will thank you later (and may even upvote).

Comment: I second what John said; please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what had happened was this: I had the following Controller method:

```
    public ActionResult SearchTitle(string path)
    {
        //lots of code here
        return Index();
    }
```

and the following route:

```
        routes.MapRoute("SearchTitle", "{*path}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "SearchTitle", path = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Since I was not using SearchTitle, I quickly deleted the method and the associated routing. This was the cause of the error.

The solution was to keep the Controller deleted, but change the routing to

```
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*path}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", path = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Note: There was never any files missing

Answer (score 2):

There are instances where visual studio will not hit a valid break point. Include system.diagnostics namespace and use debugger.break() to force a breakpoint. Remove from your code when your problem has been identified.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.aspx